# Grab URL parmeter and set select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

i am trying to get the query parameter for http://url.com?send_volume=send_300_gb and then set a form select option based on this.

I can grab the get value and assign to var to use in the assignment but for the life of me can't understand why i can't get the option to set as selected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//This will return a given query string parameter from the current url
function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var send_volume_value = getParameterByName('send_volume');

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("select[name='send_volume'] > option[value="+ send_volume_value +"]").attr('selected','selected');

});
</script>
```

Select Form looks like this:

```
<select class="hs-input" id="send_volume-33ab6f27-e084-4f5d-9690-76e8fec2316d_8893" name="send_volume">
   <option value="__PLACEHOLDER__">- Please Select -</option>
   <option value="send_300_gb">Send up to 300GB/month</option>
   <option value="send_500_gb">Send up to 500GB/month</option>
   <option value="send_1_tb">Send up to 1TB/month</option>
   <option value="send_custom">Custom</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you checked that the value returned is *exactly* equal to what you expect/believe? If it *is*, have you tried `.prop('selected',true)` (rather than using `.attr('selected','selected')`)? Are the `<option>` elements in an `<optgroup>` maybe?

Comment: What returns `$("select[name='send_volume'] > option[value="+ send_volume_value +"]").length` ?

Comment: @plalx : it has a length of "0"

Comment: @esternle That would mean there are no options with that value, or a select with name `send_volume` could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the parameter `send_volume` matches one of the values of the options for example lets say

send_volume == "testval"

and the options are

```
<select name="send_volume">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="val1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Val 3</option>
    <option value="val4">Val 4</option>
</select>
```

Then this is how you should "select" an option

```
$("select[name='send_volume']").val(send_volume);
```

Answer (score 0):

`<select>` elements do not honor the `value` attribute, however their `DOM` API does support a `value` property shich can be used to set the select's value.

```
$("select[name=send_volume]").val(send_volume_value);
```

However, the way you are doing it should also work, but I suspect that either the value of `send_volume_value` is incorrect, or there is no option with that value. Basically, there are no elements matching your selector in the document.

Comment: I don't get it, the values match (unless i am blind). I even do a alert on the page to make sure the var is set correctly.

Comment: @esternle There's not much more we can do without seeing your whole HTML.

Comment: I added the select for to the question now for the reference. This is all that i have on the page. There is also a note about the  <![CDATA[ that is being wrapped around my code in the Hubspot page...